# ClassNotFoundException when running Maven project with Spring dependencies

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have these spring dependencies in my pom.xml:

```
[...]
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
[...]
```

But when i'm running the .jar i'm getting a ClassNotFoundException caused by org.springframework.core.io.Resource
I have the spring-core dependency added, so i don't know what is it happening

**[SOLVED] Adding maven-assembly-plugin to the pom.xml like that:**

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>com.project.MainClass</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**And compiling with *mvn compile assembly:single***

Comment: You package the app as a .jar, but are the dependencies inside or present in some folder containing dependencies? (by using for example maven-dependency-plugin). By default dependencies aren't packaged inside the jar file

Comment: @Azanx They aren't, so i have to add that plugin and what is next? How does it work? Thank you for the comment, i'm newbie using maven and all this stuff.

Comment: You need to use Maven Shade plugin. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the dependencies to be linked in your jar file, one option would be to make sure [classpath](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html) is set and dependencies are copied to a folder which you will need to bundle with the packaged app. You can do that by using [maven-jar-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) and [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/usage.html), like in sample below:

```
<build>            
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.something.AppMainClassName</mainClass>
                        <classpathPrefix>dependencies</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependencies/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
</build>
```

in this way all dependencies should be present in *"dependency"* directory inside your project build directory (for example: *"target"*)

Comment: Finally i used maven-assembly-plugin and works, but your solution is correct too.